# hiding tabbar on table view cell click

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have problem with hiding tabbar .
this my code

```
//this created in the Delegate.m file 
-(void)HideTabBar
{
    mTabController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;
}

//Now i want to this on the cell select Tab bar  must hide when it go to the map view (other view ) for that i use this but its working 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JourneyAppDelegate * journey = (JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [journey HideTabBar];
}
But
```

it work how can do this

Comment: @user420220: are you pushing the View Controller **mTabController** after setting the property **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed** because it will not get hide until you push it.

Comment: But now my another problem is come. I add with this tabbar one arrowbar .i also hide like this - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES; JourneyAppDelegate * journeyarrow = (JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; journeyarrow.tabBarArrow.hidden = YES;}it work fine when i come to this page but when go back to main view the tab is shown but arrow bar not .HOw can slove thi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mTabController will not get invisible/hidden until you push it for Example:

```
//this created in the Delegate.m file 
-(void)HideTabBar
{
    mTabController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:IncomingViewController animated:YES];
}

//Now i want to this on the cell select Tab bar  must hide when it go to the map view     (other view ) for that i use this but its working 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   JourneyAppDelegate * journey = (JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   [journey HideTabBar];
}
```

You need to set **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed** property to the UIViewController that is going to be pushed before you call **pushViewController**.

Comment: I add this   self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;
into - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;} it work Thanks for your answer .I get the solution

Comment: But now my another problem  is come. I add with this tabbar one arrowbar .i also hide  like this - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;                                         JourneyAppDelegate * journeyarrow = (JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  journeyarrow.tabBarArrow.hidden = YES;}it work fine when i come to this page but when go back to main view the tab is shown but arrow bar not .HOw can slove this

Answer (score 0):

As the method suggests, it works only as the view controller is pushed onto the stack. So instead of trying to hide it in the view controller, where the table view is, just add the line
`[mapController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: YES]` to wherever you create that map controller.

Hope you understand my workings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I get the solution

Comment: But now my another problem is come. I add with this tabbar one arrowbar .i also hide like this - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES; JourneyAppDelegate * journeyarrow = (JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; journeyarrow.tabBarArrow.hidden = YES;}it work fine when i come to this page but when go back to main view the tab is shown but arrow bar not .HOw can slove thi

Comment: You can for example hide the arrow bar in the map view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method, and then enable it again in `viewWillDisappear:` In theory this should work.

Comment: I don't understand why every time my a/c closed by team please open a/c give me hint how can i open it this user a/c