# In which method should I set my UIToolBar hidden

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have been coding in iphone platform for about a few months. One thing I am still to understand is in which method exactly should I set the navigation bar/toolbar/barButtonItem hidden.

In my project sometimes I set in `- (void)viewDidLoad`, sometimes I set in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. Sometimes I set it from where I push the navigation controller.

I think I am not understanding the basics correctly. If one way is not working, I try the other way and somehow it works.

If I am to hide the toolbar or barbuttonitem in navigation controller, where exactly should I set that.

Edit:
If I am pushing a new navigation controller, in which I want my toolbar hidden, where should I set it hidden. Similarly, when I pop it, I want the the toolbar to be shown, where should I set the toolbarHidden property to 'NO'.

Similarly, I have a navigation controller, sometimes it needs to show the toolbar and sometimes it needn't, where should I check the condition for this case.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set this property before the pushing the view Controller and don't need to set No at pop. E.g see the following link:

[hiding tabbar on table view cell click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699169/hiding-tabbar-on-table-view-cell-click)